# How to change parent element property from child element?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

How can I let a child element change the value of a property in the parent element with the ability to observe that change in the parent element

```
<link rel="import" href="paper-tree-node.html">

<dom-module id="paper-tree">
  <template>
    <div>
      <paper-tree-node id="root" data="[[data]]" actions="[[actions]]" on-click='_handlePaperCheck' chapterIds={{chapterIds}}></paper-tree-node>
    </div>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({

    is: 'paper-tree',

    properties: {
      chapterIds: {
        type: Array,
        value: [],
        notify: true,
        observer: "_chapterChanged"

      }
    },
    _handlePaperCheck: function (e) {
      let element = e.target.parentElement
      if (element.checked) {
        this.push('chapterIds', parseInt(element.id.substr(2)))
        // console.info(this.chapterIds);


      } else {
        var index = this.chapterIds.indexOf(element.id);

        this.splice('chapterIds', index, 1)
        // console.info(this.chapterIds);

      }

    },
    _chapterChanged: function () {
      console.log(this.chapterIds)
      //   this.$.root.chapterIds = this.chapterIds
    }
  })
```

noting that paper-tree-node is a child element hosts a paper-check inside it's template, the purpose of this is to harvest the clicked paper-tree-node id attr and push it to the chapterIds property.

Problem is that _chapterChanged wont fire when i click on any checkbox

I am attaching a sample project since this cannot be posted on somthing like jsbin, here is a gdrive zip folder for the project https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yCeXkZu8Yp-8GUgadGHIfeP5w5uyI12J/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You want to fire an event (or use data binding) as Chris has said. One small point though, if you want the parent element of `this`, that's `this.parentElement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the right thinking, but not the entire way.

`notify: true,` should be stated in your child element `paper-tree-node` under the property `chapterIds`, and not under your `paper-tree` element. I made this mistake too when I began with Polymer.

Also, whenever Polymer sees camelCase variables, it assumes the variable contains dashes:

```
  <paper-tree-node id="root" data="[[data]]" actions="[[actions]]" on-click='_handlePaperCheck' chapterIds={{chapterIds}}></paper-tree-node>
```

... should be ...

```
  <paper-tree-node id="root" data="[[data]]" actions="[[actions]]" on-click='_handlePaperCheck' chapter-ids={{chapterIds}}></paper-tree-node>
```

... where I switched the property `chapterIds` to `chapter-ids`. I rarely use camelCase variables when creating a new element because this mistake is so easy to make.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an [event](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/events) or with [data](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/data-binding) binding.

Comment: I know, the problem is that the observer is not firing

Comment: When firing the event are you using {bubbles: true, composed: true} which is needed for an event to cross shadowDom boundaries.

Comment: No, is this part of polymer 1x

Comment: From polyme 2.x docs I liked above "By default, custom events stop at shadow DOM boundaries. To make a custom event pass through shadow DOM boundaries, set the composed flag to true when you create the event:"

Comment: Project I am working on is polymer 1x, I guess I am screwed for another week

Comment: Does _handlePaperCheck() get called?

Comment: Yes, it gets called

Comment: Can you just manually call _champterChanged? Also can you try this instead of this.push?

var tmp = [...this.chapterIds,  parseInt(element.id.substr(2))];
this.chapterIds = null;
this.chapterIds = tmp;